# Odd-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space has a one-dimensional $\varphi$-invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with odd dimension, and let $\varphi$ be an endomorphism on $V$. Show $V$ has a one-dimensional $\varphi$-invariant subspace.

I already know that $\ker f(\varphi)$ is a $\varphi$-invariant subspace for any polynomial $f$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Can I somehow use this to find the desired one-dimensional subspace of $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* The characteristic polynomial of $\varphi$ has a real root because it has odd degree.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but why are we guaranteed that the characteristic polynomial will have odd degree?

Comment: Nevermind, if the matrix representation of $\varphi$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then $n=\dim V$ and $n$ is the degree of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Then we just take the span of one of the eigenvectors.

Comment: Exactly. Well done.